# Django input validation to_python method

Tags: python, django

When a field is created in Django and its clean method is called you see a to_python method is being called.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.required

Why this (to_python) method is called when it just returns the value.

```
def clean(self, value):
    """
    Validate the given value and return its "cleaned" value as an
    appropriate Python object. Raise ValidationError for any errors.
    """
    value = self.to_python(value)
    self.validate(value)
    self.run_validators(value)
    return value


def to_python(self, value):
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the default implementation. The method is there so you can override how your object is turned into a Python value if you use more customized things, like special Field overrides. [Here's the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects)

It contains a nice example showing a class that overrides this method:

```
def parse_hand(hand_string):
    """Takes a string of cards and splits into a full hand."""
    p1 = re.compile('.{26}')
    p2 = re.compile('..')
    args = [p2.findall(x) for x in p1.findall(hand_string)]
    if len(args) != 4:
        raise ValidationError(_("Invalid input for a Hand instance"))
    return Hand(*args)

class HandField(models.Field):
    # ...

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
           return value
        return parse_hand(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Hand):
            return value

        if value is None:
            return value

        return parse_hand(value)
```